# Im getting error in Nullpointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

someone plz help me My app is getting Crash when im run the project

```
            if (!Constant_Api.aboutUsList.getInterstital_ad_click().equals("")) {
                Constant_Api.AD_COUNT_SHOW = Integer.parseInt(Constant_Api.aboutUsList.getInterstital_ad_click());
            }


 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.app.singlehotel.Item.AboutUsList.getInterstital_ad_click()' on a null object reference
    at com.app.singlehotel.Activity.MainActivity$2.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:266)
```

Comment: add full code and where you declare getInterstital_ad_click()?

Comment: post here the line #266 from MainActivity.java

Comment: Here My Code https://pastr.io/raw/pvy842

Comment: this is not how you get help on stack overflow. add the code which could be causing these issues to your original question by editing it. you need to provide as much info as possible for others to help

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as well as https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It would also be a good time on how to learn how to use Android Studio's debugger.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that it is necessary to check if the `Constant_Api.aboutUsList == null` before calling `getInterstital_ad_click()` on it.

As the stacktrace points to invoking 
`java.lang.String com.app.singlehotel.Item.AboutUsList.getInterstital_ad_click()` so I don't believe it is making it to the `.equals()` check.

Update:
It appears the offending line is within the if statement given within the original post. It is likely that the `ConstantApi.AboutUsList` is null. I am not entirely sure what it is because it is an import, but my best guess is that it is null because it is being defined within the scope of the for loop.

Test `ConstantApi.AboutUsList == null` before trying to invoke any methods on it, namely `getInterstital_ad_click()`. If it is null, you need to instantiate it within the correct scope.

Ps. thanks [@a-local-nobody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4729721/a-local-nobody) for the comments regarding my post as well as the question and supplied code.

Comment: getting error It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.